# URL Redirection Issue in DNN

Tags: url, dotnetnuke

In my local environment of a particular site, when i click on a particular link ,it redirects to the same page but in the url it shows that the page has been visited.Again when i click on the link, it will direct me to that page. Any reason as to why this happens and what could be the possible solution.
For example: My sites name is abc.com. It has pages like help, contact etc. When i am on my homepage and click on help it redirects me back to my home page but in my browser the URL is shown as abc.com/help.
When i click on help again , it redirects me to the help page(URL in browser is abc/help/Help) on the second click.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the cache or system index has been corrupted.  The best solution is to typically stop & start the application and see if it comes back.

If it is still an issue and you are on an older version of DNN, make sure that the PortalAlias table doesn't have a trailing / on your portal alias.

If this isn't the case, it is possible that a custom URL impacted this, but doubtful.